# Reduce the area of the Bootstrap carousel chevron (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a working Bootstrap 4 carousel and inside some images.

The issue is that the user can slide the carousel NOT ONLY on the chevron itself but on a very large zone (a sort or rectangle). How can I prevent this so that user don't slide when they click outside of the very chevron ?

```
<div id="list-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">      
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
              <!-- responsive image -->
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">             
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              lorem ipsum
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="item ">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/450x200">             
            <div class="carousel-caption">              
                Hotel room in LA
            </div>
          </div>          
      </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#list-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa chevron fa-chevron-left "></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carou[![enter image description here][1]][1]sel-control" href="#prize-list-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa chevron fa-chevron-right "></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

And here is via Chrome Developer tool the whole zones where, when clicked makes the carousel "slide on". (the zone below appears when I select on chrome dev tools the line )

[image]

As you see the zone where he can click is much larger than the chevron/arrow itself. That's the issue.

To be sure it was not coming from a tweak or sth specific in my app, I checked here too a online BS carousel: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/pjJGQE, and it's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override Bootstrap with:

```
.carousel-control {
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/ZLQNLW)

Beware that it's a very large zone for a reason: it's way easier for an user to click and interact with the carousel, even on mobile or with images of different heights and widths (not sure BS manages this but it happens in the wild). That may not be what you intend, but it's a given for a lot of users now: they expect to be able to click very far from the chevron and still see the action they expect to happen.

Also UX SE has something to say about [carousels](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective) ^^

Comment: thanks for your answer, let me try and yes I understand what you mean for mobile UX :  i'll read your suggested link and actually I kind of understand that on mobnile we're used to "near/about the zone" clicks but on a desktop with very large viewport, then the user would not understand that if he clicks randomly somewhere between the chevron and the image can be very far as width (and heights actually) of images will vary in my slide , that it does trigger the slide to "move on"...clicking in a huge empty space should not trigger it on desktop for me. it"s an unexpected behavior.

Comment: maybe i can keep the current situation for mobile / small screens and change behavior for larger screens

Comment: another option I'm thinking now thanks to your answer is that, maybe it's the position of the chevron that is problematic: it changes given each image... maybe I'll manage that it always stays very near the image/even inside it...

Comment: in terms of UX note that mine is not a hero carousel on top of a HP=> it's a modal popin called by the user when he clicks on a certain button...and it's really a way to tell , step by step (slide by slide) a story. so it's not the case of "Why Users Aren’t Clicking Your Home Page Carousel" and oh my users are missing crucial info or not clicking on the CTA we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your css

```
.carousel-control {
   width: 25px;
}
```

Perhaps you have to add margin too and remove background ?

```
.carousel-control {
    width: 25px;
    background: none;
    margin: 0 5%;
}
```

Comment: your first proposal .carousel-control {width: 25px;} works , but only partly: it actually 'thicken'/reduce the width of the rectangle I show in my image. I have a much smaller rectangle but still have it. It means if I put my mouse below (even much below) the chevron i'm still in the 25px width and it "slides on" when clicked

Comment: the secon suggestion does not add anything compared to your first sugg. i'm pushing forward

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but you can try it

Remove the data-slide="prev" in the a tag and add it in the span tag